# Default cookies and compliance

Tags: cookie, magento2.4.4

Do Magento (2.4.x) by it's default settings, with no extensions like GoogleAnalytics installed, require the need of the customer to accept cookies?

Newish EU statements tells that the customer do not need to be informed about / accept cookies that is required to serve the shop. Eg like cookies that is required for the shopping cart to work.

The customer needs to accept Marketing/Statistic cookies, but do Magento by default collect any of these information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unnecessary cookies are used by magento by default.

You can use a cookie editor to see cookie info and what is create to be sure.

No obligation to display a message for cookies by default for the EU compliance.

If you need to display a message you can use the module : Mageplaza_BetterPopup (free)